# Filter assosciated collection in JPA query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, jpql

Given the following domain model

```
Message ---< MessageReply >--- User
```

Or in terms of the entity classes

```java
public class Message {
    @Id
    private UUID id;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "message")
    private Set<MessageReply> replies;
}
    
public class MessageReply {
    @Id
    private UUID id;
    
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User sentByUser;
    
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "message_id")
    private Message message;
}
```

I'm trying to write a JPQL query that returns a message by ID along with any replies sent by a particular user. Ideally, I would like the replies to be eagerly loaded. If the message doesn't have any replies it should be returned, so I need to use a left-join to the the replies.

In my Spring Data repository, I've tried various options e.g.

```java
@Query("from Message m " +
    "left join fetch m.replies mr on mr.user.id = :userId " +
    "where m.id = :messageId")
Optional<Message> getMessage(UUID userId, UUID messageId);
```

The attempt above yields an error

> with-clause not allowed on fetched associations; use filters

I've also tried moving the user predicate to the where clause, but I either get nothing returned, or the message is returned with replies from all users.

Is it even possible to filter associated collections in the query itself? If not, I guess I'll post-process the result of the query to remove replies from other users.

Comment: if you want the message id and list of messageReply instances, why not just query on MessageReply and their associated message id? "select m.id, mr from Message m left join m.replies mr where mr.sentByUser = :userId". This query will return multiple MessageReply instances for the same message ID that you then would need to build your own collection for - you can build Message instances from the data yourself, or just return a map of Ids and MesageReply sets - but the advantage is that it doesn't limit your object model to alway have to filter these collections by a particular user.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use hibernate [@Filter](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-filter).

1. You should correct your entity mapping in the following way:

```java
public class Message {
    @Id
    private UUID id;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "message")
    @Filter(
        name="messagesForUser",
        condition="user_id = :userId"
    )
    private Set<MessageReply> replies;
}
```

2. You should correct your query:

```java
@Query("select m from Message m left join fetch m.replies where m.id = :messageId")
Optional<Message> getMessage(UUID messageId);
```

3. And then you can use it in the following way:

```java
entityManager
    .unwrap(Session.class)
    .enableFilter("messagesForUser")
    .setParameter("userId", userId);

Optional<Message> message = yourRepo.getMessage(messageId);
```

P.S. As it's stated in the hibernate documentation:

> Filters apply to entity queries, *but not to direct fetching*.

Therefore, in the following example, the filter is not taken into consideration when fetching an entity from the Persistence Context.

```java
entityManager
    .unwrap(Session.class)
    .enableFilter("messagesForUser")
    .setParameter("userId", userId);

Message message = entityManager.find(Message.class, messageId);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't work out. I got an error at runtime that indicate the filter "messagesForUser" is not registered. I tried adding a `@FilterDef` annotation to `Message`, but I got a NullPointerException when executing the query.